# WinForms/Console application on Mono, how to know it runs as root

Tags: c#, mono, opensuse

As we can execute such executables in two ways, such as "sudo mono test.exe", and "mono test.exe".

Now I want to know how to detect whether this application is running as root inside the application itself.

I tried to check user name like below and see whether they equal to "root",

Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name

Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartInfo.UserName

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ApplicationIdentity.FullName

The first two are empty strings always, while the third throws NullReferenceException.

Please advise if this is doable on Mono 2.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to `DllImport` libc and use the `getuid()` function.  If you're running as root, `getuid()` returns 0; if not, it returns some other UID:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Program
{
    [DllImport ("libc")]
    public static extern uint getuid ();

    public static void Main()
    {
        if (getuid() == 0) {
            System.Console.WriteLine("I'm running as root!");
        } else {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Not root...");
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine in Mono 2.6.

EDIT: It might be better to access `getuid()` through the Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall wrapper class in the Mono.Posix assembly:

```
using Mono.Unix.Native;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        if (Syscall.getuid() == 0) {
            System.Console.WriteLine("I'm running as root!");
        } else {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Not root...");
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, I'm not much of a Mono expert.  But however you get to it, the process's UID is what you want to know; if it's equal to zero then you're root, otherwise you're not root.

Comment: Thanks. I choose to use Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.getuid() finally, as this assembly can also be used on Windows.